# Let user publish posts on community page

Tags: theme-development, multisite, publish, community

I want to create a theme that lets the user publish posts (or all posts in an entire category at once) on a certain WordPress page.

The user should be able to write and edit those posts and if one feels ready, there is a button that allows to publish the post not only on ones own page, but also on a cummunity page, where all these articles flow together and can be voted.

I don't know if and how this could be done and would be thankful for any hint into the right direction.

Comment: If you want to add a vote system, it's more with a plugin instead that a theme. You can add votes to the inital posts of WordPress or create a custom post type https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types

Comment: It's not just about voting. The users can download the theme. Then they can write posts, publish them on their own site like they normally would. But I want to enable them to publish it on the main site, too, if they wish to. The main site is totally separate from their own. It is hosted by me under a certain adress. All posts that are published there can be voted upon, but this is not the part that causes me problems. I dont know how to make it possible to publish that post on another page.